# Scroll-Wheel action possibly over-ridden on MVC Application

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, mouse

This may get shot down for ambiguity but I am hoping someone may at least be able to point me in the right direction. I work with a team on a large MVC application. It seems at some point (no one is holding their hand up) someone must have introduced some code that seems to be overriding the entire sites ability to scroll with the mouse wheel. The scroll bars work fine when you drag the slider but everything else in the pages that need to scroll with the mouse wheel no longer do.

I was there-for wondering if anyone has any debug tips or anything to help point me in the right direction to get this resolved. Im having a poke around in Chromes Developer Tools but not really seeing anything.

Hope someone is able to help in some way!

Comment: do you see the scroll bar on the right ?

Comment: Is the scrollbar the native browser scrollbar, or is it replaced by a custom jquery scrollbar?

Comment: The scroll bar is there and fully functional when you drag the scroll bar up and down (I am pretty sure it is not a custom one). It is exclusively the mouse wheel input that is not being recognized.